# Watson Document Conversion

Tags: python, ibm-watson, watson

Below is my code for the IBM Watson document conversion. I keep on getting the error message below when I try to run script in Python. I have my username and password XXXX'd out in the code below, but I have copied and pasted my active username and password so I do not know what would be causing the credential issue. Any help would be appreciated.

> watson_developer_cloud.watson_developer_cloud_service.WatsonException:
>   Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials

```
import json
from os.path import join, dirname
from watson_developer_cloud import DocumentConversionV1

document_conversion = DocumentConversionV1(
    username="XXXXXXXXXXX",
    password="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    version='2015-12-15')

with open(join(dirname(__file__), 'a16-23019_2nq.htm'),
      'r') as document:
    config = {'conversion_target':DocumentConversionV1.NORMALIZED_HTML}
    print(document_conversion.convert_document(
        document=document, config=config, media_type='text/html').content)
```

Answer (score 1):

Drew, I do not know if you're using your Bluemix credentials, but if it is, it will not work because in the case IBM Request the **Service Credentials**.

In case you should `get` the credentials of the service inside the "Document Conversion" as shown in the `attached` image below.
If you are putting the credentials and it still is not working, try code 2.

Example:

```
document_conversion = DocumentConversionV1(
    username='67bxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxx',
    password='fWxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    version='2016-02-09')
```

or Try it with JSON format:

```
document_conversion = DocumentConversionV1(
  username='{username}',
  password='{password}',
  version='2015-12-15'
)
```

**Step 1, click on the link:**

[image]

**Step 2, Get credentials and enter in your code:**

[image]

If you have more questions, you can see this [example](http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/document-conversion/api/v1/?python#introduction) and this [link](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/blob/master/examples/document_conversion_v1.py) with the examples from Watson Document Service (Python) and I'll try answer to help you too.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the userid and password the right way round. This is a common mistake, the way you can tell is that the userid will be long and the password will be short.

Comment: Simple solution. Had the password/username backwards. Thank you.